# Loading one single constant into jvm among several constants

Tags: java, memory, constants, static-members

In my code i have to use some constant values, so I created a utility class

```
public class ConstantUtility {
    public final static String category1_name1="category1/name1";
    public final static String category1_name2="category1/name2";
    public final static String category1_name3="category1/name3";
    .
    .
    .
    public final static String category2_name100="category2/name100";
    public final static String category2_name101="category2/name101";
    .
    .
    .
}
```

But i have like 2000 constant values i don't use all those values in my application but they should be there as a choice. The problem is when i use the utility class all variables are static variables and all string values get loaded into jvm.

The 2000 constants are divided into 6 categories. I tried using 6 static classes but still its the same. When jvm finds a static class it loads every static variable into memory.

Comparing to the string constant memory i really use to all those constants memory which i don't use getting loaded into the jvm is far greater.

Question: How can i load only single constant into memory among all those constants.

Comment: If this is what they really look like there is no need for any of them. Just compute them as you need them

Comment: @EJP i don't get what you are trying to say. Are you suggesting to use the static variables.

Comment: You don't need to store 2000 strings of the form `"/category"+i+"/name"+j`. You can compute the ones you need at runtime.

Comment: I am not sure if you should worry about performance unless you actually have a "performance problem". In a production level system 2000 constants   isn't too bad. Also, Public static final Strings are compile time constants, they would greaetly speed up your app.

Comment: If this example isn't real, it is unclear what you're asking, but if there is any rule to how they're built, you can just apply the rule.

Comment: @EJP category are something like application, audio,... not category 1, 2.. same goes for the names too. I gave that just for example.

Comment: @TheLostMind you are right it's more like a memory issue but code will be used for webapp so will not be a problem.But I feel it as very bad design.

Comment: @Sudheer - Well, 2K strings is indeed a *not-so-good* design. You could generate them dynamically like EJP says.

Comment: @EJP,@TheLostMind - how about enums. if I use enums can that do any good.

Comment: You need to provide some concrete examples, but for a start I would normalise this. You only have six categories, for example, so you don't need to explode all possible combinations of categories and names. I would seriously still consider not having any of these constants at all, and letting string pooling work its magic.

Answer (score 3):

And just to be sure: you are asking this because you are doing some "embedded kind of" project; and you ran into memory issues; and you did profiling/analysis and found that having those 2000 strings is in deed a problem within your application? Because: if you didn't do any of that - what makes you think that you actually have a problem that requires you to spent time on it?

And a side note: the fact alone that you have 2000 constants; many of them "unused" ... very much indicates that you should worry less about the effects on such a design on memory consumption; but on the design itself.

Honestly, this smells badly in terms of "probably not a very good design" in the first place.

Comment: I agreewith Jagermeister, @Sudheer, You are expecting machine to do .5 which only understand 0 or 1

Comment: @Sudheer, What I mean is JVM will either load nothing means 0 or  all constants which means 1. It can't do half job. Using Constants have their pros and cons. One of the disadvantage not quite often counted is the problem you are facing. You need to re-structure the way constants are defined. So that one group of constants are defined in one class. If memory usage is primary concern then group constants based on functionality, not application wide.

Answer (score 2):

You could create properties-files. Those are simple text files where you can store key-value pairs and parse them using standard Java classes: [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html)

Then you can load only the files you need. You said you divided your values into 6 categories. You could create 6 files and load only the one file you need when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a practice one sees often.

- In a team it causes unnecessary version control cycles/merges.
- The compiler will in a using source import the constant in the class itself, and the in the .class will no longer reside the import of the constants' class. So if a constant receives another value, an obsolete value remains in the using class (manual clean+build needed).
- New code is splitted into two places, which is not "flowing" as fast as possible, also for search and reading.

As you mentioned one can alleviate the problem by having for several constants defining classes / interfaces / enums.

Alternatives (to some degree) exist. JAXB allows to marshal between XML and java objects.

```
@XmlAttribute("surname")
public String surname; // <... surname="...">
```

The annotation above can be removed as the field has the exact name.
By the way: do not introduce constants for annotation values, as annotations can be processed.

This shows two ways of introducing constants, and I add enum:

- by annotation - processable in java
- by reflection (inefficient though)
- by enum: `enum Category1 { name1, name2 }`

Admittedly it must fit the use-case.

Business logic seems the largest problem: many small domains and case specific code to handle business rules. The domain values can be generated as enum from the database (or vice versa).

Comment: How does one generate an enum from the database? The enum’s instances are predetermined at compile time, are they not?

Comment: @BasilBourque Sorry I meant one can generate for DB tables with SQL enums or the value rows java sources which then need to be compiled.

Comment: I suggest you expand on this in your Answer. I think you are talking about programmatically generating the text for Java source code to then be compiled in the app, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes a small application that queries the database and generates a java enum or such. It very much depends on what constants, so I'll refrain from writing something. Start writing such a tool, when one made such a class by hand, and more values are expected in future. Put all those generated sources in a separated library project for versioning.

Answer (score -2):

Basically, While loading a class, JVM load all static variables and hold it into memory. If you want to load only the constants on demand. You have to write certain logic using system commands and invoke from Java code. Or move all constants to a file and retrieve the required constants whenever needed. But It is performance wise not that much good.

Comment: Yes, Move your constant to a file, And execute 'grep' command with your constant name and load the result into java variable.

Comment: @JPBose - No, that's not the right way of doing things. That's actually a horrible way both in terms of design and performance.

Comment: @TheLostMind is correct i don't want to use static for this problem because that would be a bad design and calling native code from java code is performance overhead.